# Excel - Two Cells, Either is Input, Other is result of formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA for inputting in Excel to either of two cells... the cell not getting input is filled in with a formula result based on the input from the other.
Example;

Cells B4, C4 & D4.

B4 is manually entered, then C4 gets manual input and the C4 formula determines the result for D4... Or... D4 gets manual input and the D4 formula determines the result for C4.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Address = "$C$4" Or Target.Address = "$D$4" Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Target.Address = "$C$4" Then
            Range("D4").Value = B4 * C4
        Else
            Range("C4").Value = D4 / B4

        End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```

I keep getting the *Run-Time '6': Overflow* error - specifically on the *Range("C4").Value = D4 / B4* statement.

Nothing I try seems to solve this... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBE thinks that `B4 * C4` is referring to two varibles named B4 and C4 respectively.

To refer to a range it should be `Range("B4").Value * Range("C4").Value`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    If Target.Address = "$C$4" Or Target.Address = "$D$4" Then    
        Application.EnableEvents = False    
        If Target.Address = "$C$4" Then
            Range("D4").Value = Range("B4").Value * Range("C4").Value
        Else
            Range("C4").Value = Range("D4").Value / Range("B4").Value    
        End If    
        Application.EnableEvents = True    
    End If    
End Sub
```

One could also use the `[]` around the ranges as a shorthand:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$4" Or Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Address = "$C$4" Then
            [D4] = [B4] * [C4]
        Else
            [C4] = [D4] / [B4]
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Also since `EnableEvents` does not reset when the code ends and it is possible to get an error. We need to capture the error and turn the events back on before exiting.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$4" Or Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
        On Error GoTo SafeOut
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Address = "$C$4" Then
            [D4] = [B4] * [C4]
        Else
            [C4] = [D4] / [B4]
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
Exit Sub
SafeOut:
MsgBox "Error occured, check values"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This way if someone put `0` in B4, which would cause a `#Div/0` error, the events get turned back on and a msgbox tells the user to fix the values.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks Scott... that did the trick... nice pick-up/correction !
Also slick with the B4 error check.
Much appreciated.

Comment: @Phil please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.